# Сделать создание постоянных ссылок в посте динамическим с нужными именами

Tags: php, wordpress

Сейчас wordpress создаёт постоянную ссылку в посте на основании заголовка поста, которое на русском. Я же хочу на английском. У меня есть произвольное поле english-movie-title, которое я добавляю к URL сайта. Я написал хук. Проблема:
При публикации ссылка создаётся на русском. А в админ панели после публикации при редактировании хук срабатывает, и я вижу ссылку уже на английском языке, но при переходе пост пустой. Как мне изменить хук, чтобы решить свою задачу?

```html
function movieapp_filter_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ){
    $site_url = get_site_url();
    $field = get_field( 'english-movie-title', $post->ID );
    $eng_mov_tit = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$field));
    $permalink = $site_url . '/' . $eng_mov_tit . '/';
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'movieapp_filter_post_link', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вашу задачу, вы хотите менять урл поста при сохранении. А меняете урл поста при выводе. Ожидаемо получаете 404 страницу на выходе, т. к. Wordpress ничего не знает о том адресе, по которому вы пытаетесь что-то получить.

Вам необходимо сохранять slug поста при его создании, а не вешать фильтры на получение его адреса. То есть действие на `save_post`, а не на `post_link`

Что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php
function change_post_slug_callback($post_id, $post, $update) {
    // проверяем, что тип поста "post" и это не автосохранение, иначе выходим
    if ($post->post_type != 'post' || $post->post_status == 'auto-draft')
        return;

    // меняем адрес только если пост содаётся, а не редактируется (проверка на совпадение даты создания и даты редактирования)
    // удалите эту часть, если вам нужна возможность менять урл при редактировании
    if ($post->post_date_gmt != $post->post_modified_gmt)
        return;

    // здесь получение нового слэга по вашему алгоритму, что бы он ни значил    
    $field = get_field( 'english-movie-title', $post->ID);
    $new_slug = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$field))
    
    // проверяем, что новый слэг не совпадает с предыдущим, иначе выходим
    if ($new_slug == $post->post_name)
        return;

    // отключаем наш экшн чтобы избежать зацикливания при сохранении (это важная часть, не исключайте её)
    remove_action('save_post', 'change_post_slug_callback', 10, 3 );
    
    // устанавливаем новый слэг и сохраняем пост
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $new_slug
    ));
    
    // возвращаем экшн
    add_action('save_post', 'change_post_slug_callback', 10, 3);
}
add_action('save_post', 'change_post_slug_callback', 10, 3);
```